# Linux: Sign PDF using a certificate stored in a smart card with a time-stamped signature

Tags: linux, pdf, certificate, smartcard

In Linux, I am looking for a way to sign a PDF file using a certificate stored in a smart card similar to the feature offered by adobe acrobat reader (Tools->Certificates->Digitally Sign). The latter allows the user to place a signature inside the PDF and then after providing a pin it puts a time-stamped signature.

Is this possible? If yes, please provide a free solution if available. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly something like [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/opensignature/code/HEAD/tree/opensignpdf/trunk/)?. You'll want to look for OpenSC / cryptoki = PKCS#11 support. Many old abandoned projects... many of them using Java because platform independence and cryptoki support (and the iText library, of course).

Comment: Yes, true many abandoned projects exist like the one the link points to. Although I tried it and I didn't manage to make it work as it lacks also the display of error messages, it has the limitation that you don't specify where the sign will be put unless you have inserted a signature field from openoffice (don't know if it applies for libreoffice). I tried also puting a signature with libreoffice and run the software but still doesn't work, no error... and thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Check one available at https://web.signer.digital - Browser Extension for Linux is also available.